# Would a carbonfiber sword/katana be useful?

Tags: weapons

Carbonfiber is said to be lighter and stronger than steel. Would it be a material of choice for building swords in modern times? Disregarding price, is it possible to make it as sharp as a steel sword? Would it shatter upon impact with something hard?

Comment: Being too light is not necessarily a good property for a weapon. The heavier a weapon, the more momentum behind its strikes and the deeper it penetrates when swung. However, this doesn't apply that much for thrusting attack. Compare the shape of a machete (made for hacking) with that of an epee (made for thrusting).

Comment: I thought it might interest you to know that a lot of LRP weapons use carbon fiber or fiberglass cores :D That's a very different use-case to real weapons though.

Comment: Snowboards and skis are often heavy on the composite in the body, but I have yet to see one with a carbon fibre rather than a steel edge. I assuming that this is for a very good reason.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Carbon fibre and many of the super materials that have been developed in the last several decades (Kevlar, Spectra, M5 and so on) are generally fibres which are amazingly strong in tension. While this has many fantastic properties, this by itself isn't going to help you make a sword.

To illustrate, think of the fact that spider silk is something like 17X stronger than steel by weight. A strand of spider silk can take 17X more force in tension than a similar strand of steel of equal weight. OTOH, trying to make a sword of spider silk will result in a large, floppy mess. You will probably be able to successfully entangle the opponent with such a weapon rather than slicing him in half.

Most carbon fibre items like skis, arrows, car doors, 787's and so on are composites, which use carefully aligned bundles of carbon fibre to provide strength in tension, and other materials to provide strength in compression. Composites also need a strong binding material in order to keep the fibres in place (traditional boat makers will recognize the goopy resin used to keep the glass fibre in place).

Since a sword (or most striking/cutting weapons) require strength in compression, carbon fibre by itself would not make for a useful sword blade. A composite blade could be made as a "sandwich" of a central steel cutting blade and carbon fibre "slabs" on either side to provide a very stiff, lightweight blade. As an aside, the traditional Katana was a very complex 3d object which also used a sandwich of hard, brittle steel in the middle to hold the cutting edge and softer steel on either side and on the non cutting "back" edge to provide flexibility and the ability to absorb blows without the blade snapping, so a composite sword could be "tuned" to provide different sorts of performance (a rapier like blade would benefit greatly by being stiffened by a lot of carbon fibre, while a traditional longsword used the weight of the blade to provide more of the motive and cutting force through chain mail armour, so a lighter longsword might not be as effective beyond a certain point).

So if your aim is to make or deploy a composite blade, study the nature of the fighting style and the sorts of armour/defense it was supposed to penetrate to understand why the blade is built the way it was, and then work with that. There is a reason that different cultures and time periods used different types of swords.

Comment: While I agree with the first three paragraphs, I have to take exception with the fourth; there is a purposeful difference between the construction of a katana and European swords. From the high gothic period onwards, longswords (which were only a touch heavier - but quite a bit longer - than katanas) and rapiers were made of monometal, specifically spring steel. The reason was that the blade, when exposed to significant force perpendicular to its spine, would flex rather than bend or break and the swords could thus take a lot more punishment in e.g. parrying. Monometallic construction [...]

Comment: also did not have any welds, on which there was always a risk of introducing impurities and thus could be a weakness (which is something to keep in mind when bonding steel to carbon fiber). Profile of the blade (diamond-shape for rapiers, I-beam generally for longswords) would make sure that the blade would remain rigid in the thrust. I rather suspect that using CF to stiffen the blade of a rapier or a longsword would only lead to the sandwiching snapping off during the first heavy parry (against an axe or such), as CF is more fragile than spring steel. In comparison, a katana is [...]

Comment: proportionately heavier than a longsword with the blade much thicker, but more rigid (with a tendency towards bending rather than flexing); this is so that the steel core that forms the blade edge can be comparatively harder (~60 rockwell vs. 50-55 for longswords) and thus slightly better to hold an edge, which is more important for cutting. Here you might use the carbon fiber to better effect; I suppose that after encasing it in mild steel (to prevent it from snapping in a parry) and sandwiching it around the hard steel core you might get a blade that is lighter and more resistant to bending.

Comment: I once worked with someone who made a knife out of carbon fiber composite.  It certainly looked impressive, and was amazingly lightweight, but it couldn't hold an edge long enough to cut a sandwich, much less a knight in shining armor.

Comment: @Mark you don't cut a knight in shining armor, you smash him with a warhammer, or throw him on the floor and take him captive with a dagger to his exposed joints for ransom.

Comment: Indeed. The appearance of plate armour was the end of the broadsword and its replacement with smashing weapons like gamers and maces, while the sword itself evolved towards a thrusting blade which became the ancestor of the rapier

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the characteristics of the sword. Remember that carbon fiber composite (CFC) is made up of carbon fibers held together by epoxy (genetally speaking). To get a fine cutting you'd be sharpening the epoxy which is a bad cutting edge. When a sword strikes something, it experiences impact forces. CFC has very poor impact resistance. It will delaminate. In tension, fibers carry the load so it is very strong and in compression, the epoxy carries most of the load so it is weaker. CFC is lighter so the strikes will have less energy in them.

Now with these limitations in mind, you could probably build a katana with using CFC as the core. Then have Kevlar composite on the outside. Kevlar has better impact properties than CFC. The cutting edge could be of any metal of choice that can be sharpend. The blunt edge could be of some high strength steel.

The use of a sword like this would probably be for speed and agility due to it being very light. Blocking a strike or striking a hard surface such as armor can damage the composite. This means that this sword would probably require precise cuts in strategic locations like on unarmored locations or between armor platings.

Answer (score 3):

Swords require good values in many primary properties (hardness, toughness, tensile strength, compressive strength, & shear strength) and benefit from good values in other secondary properties (corrosion resistance, cost, durability, etc.).

The super material fibers mentioned above possess fantastic values for a single property (tensile strength) but possess significantly worse values in the other primary properties (hardness, toughness, compressive, etc.).

The reason we still use steel instead of other materials is because generally speaking it provides the best over all performance of the materials we've tried.

I **do** think that modern materials science could "build a better sword" now but I'm not sure anyone has spent significant engineering design effort figuring out what the ideal blends of materials are and how to composite them for best effect.

@Youstay Igo mentions a titanium cutting edge and this might be a good addition (titanium has high hardness).  But can we do better?

Some things to consider:

- Hardness on the point & cutting edge
- Toughness in the center & on edge opposite of cutting edge (for
  single edged swords)
- Ideally cutting edge kept in compression by means of carefully
  cycling between heating, quenching, and annealing the sword.
- Composite fibers (which ones?!  [Boron Nitride fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boron_nitride#Properties) possess fantastic
  material properties but are exceedingly hard to work with) may
  be used to strengthen the portions of the sword in tension.
- Cutting edge might benefit from the application of [ceramic coatings (synthetic sapphire or diamond?)](http://www.gavish.com/sapphire-coating-metallization.htm)
- Steel would be our starting point and we'd look for materials that
  could outperform steel in specific roles (e.g. [high nickel "super alloys"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superalloy) might possess
  better mechanical properties than typical sword steels).

Answer (score 1):

About the sharpness, specifically: Not unless coated with something else. A carbon fibre material is nonhomogenous, and any refined edge put on it (if you even could - see below) would very quickly degrade due to impact or wear having an uneven effect on the constituents of the material. The sharpness of real world knives is actually limited by the choice of steel alloy, since homogenity of a steel differs depending on alloy and heat treatment -  a satisfactory razor or sashimi knife can be made from fine grained steels like 13C26 (stainless) or pure carbon steels, but not from eg D2 tool steel or conventional (non powder metallurgical) HSS steels since it is practically very difficult to abrade a material that has coarse, very hard inclusions evenly enough and keep it even.

That said, many sword types do not depend on being as sharp as the material would allow.

Answer (score 0):

[This forum](http://www.swordforum.com/forums/showthread.php?65693-Carbon-fiber-sword) suggests it is possible to build a carbon fiber blade but deems it a bad choice for swords.

> **Question:** Would it be possible to make a good sword out of carbon fiber? Would it keep an edge and be flexible enough? I am interseted to see how this will work out because carbon fiber is so light. Thank you in advance.
>  
> **Answer:** Oh, and no, you can't make a good sword out of carbon fiber. The weight and balance necessary for cutting wouldn't work out too hot. You could potentially make a spear, but I recall a knife maker saying carbon fiber blades are very resilient, but terrible at edge/point holding due to exposed fibers...they work fine for impact tools (like a long rod used for mock lightsabers) but... otherwise no, knives and swords out of carbon fiber don't work...

[This Q-A](https://www.quora.com/Would-a-sword-made-out-of-carbon-fiber-be-effective) also suggests that a CF blade would be sturdy and long lasting, but not much effective at slicing and dicing.

> **Question:** Would a sword made out of carbon fiber be effective?
> **Answer:** It would depend on the type of "effectiveness" you require. Probably fine for stabbing. Hard to say about slicing. Steel could probably be worked and sharpened to a finer edge which is less fragile than ceramic kitchen knives. It would depend how sharp you could make the carbon fiber, and whether it would shatter if it hit bone. 
> A great samurai sword is worked and folded with two kinds of steel, one more flexible, one less. Could you toss a red silk up in the air and part it when it lands on a carbon fiber sword edge as in the Kevin Costner/Whitney Houston movie?  Try it and see.

Most sword builders on the web indicate that if you get the edge on the blade made of titanium and keep the rest of blade carbon-fiber, that would be the best sturdy, slicing sword you could get with modern tech.

Comment: Could you summarise the arguments indicated by your first link? Link have a tendency to disappear. Similarly, "Most Sword builders on the web", could you give the example of one such?

Comment: I guess I have presented the summary of the post in link 1. Similarly, the verdict of the 2nd link has been presented. If OP has any question with my answer, he can ask it himself. No?

Comment: "deems it a bad choice" isn't a summary. The second link is better. The OP might ask himself, but seeing from the rep, he is quite new here, and might not do it. Plus we are all responsible for the quality of the questions and answers. And I think your answer could be improved, thus my comments.

Comment: You are very much invited by me to improve my answer by reading the links and adding a summary of their content. No objection from my side whatsoever. What else?

Comment: I think Bilbo's point is that your answer shouldn't rely on links for its value as links can go dead in the future at which point a user looking would find no value in your answer.  Paraphrasing the content on the other site (with a reference back to the site and author) is the preferred method on SE.

Comment: That's what I **did** in my answer. Gave a one line verdict and presented a link to the original content.

Comment: @YoustayIgo One line is generally not enough, and I don't think it's enough here. For example, you should explain *why* the first forum things it's possible.

Comment: Happy now, eh ?

Answer (score -1):

The only purpose I can see a carbon fiber sword for; is a bokken/bokudo, and it would probably need an aluminum core. It possibly would be more prone to shattering, than the cheapest wood bokken, and you don't want CF to shatter. The aluminum core would add a flexible strength to it, because CF does bend under stress, it is normally stiff, not being xesigned to bend. CF bike forks are some of rhe stiffest out there, and they're hollow, so on could only imagine a layered "folded" CF bokken; shaped, then  ot only vacuum formed, but with a bit of heat. I imagine more deadly than a baseball bat, with quick consequtive hits, especially if one has trained with heavier swords(wood or metal).

Comment: Your answer is very difficult to read. You should consider breaking your answer up into paragraphs, correcting your spelling and grammar errors, and maybe splitting some of those sentences into multiple ones.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my response, aside from a few spelling errors. It is one paragraph(a paragraph is a minimum of six sentences), and I doubt there is any grammar errors- if you mean PUNCTUATION, then, nor is there much of that either.